# Architecture Token Authentication: Web API, Xamarin and External Authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, xamarin

**Background**

I'm developing an app using Xamarin (app) and a Web API (Endpoints). The app does not implement its own authentication and it uses External Authentication (Google, Facebook, Twitter). Xamarin has something to deal with External Authentication called `Xamarin.Auth`.

**Question**

I understand how `Xamarin.Auth` works and how to store the access token. But I still have some questions that I didn't find answers for.

1. How would my Web API will know it has authenticated and now should allow to access the endpoints?
2. Should i still need the Token Authentication mechanism in place for my app and API to communicate securely?
3. Can i use the same token created by external authentication service and store in database and use it to communicate between ? If so how would i encounter situation where token is not valid?

**UPDATE 1**

I still have some confusion and questions regarding the workflow, so created a diagram.

[image]

1. oAuth 2.0(Google,Facebook,others).
2. Client receives token from External Authentication.
3. Client calls the API. **At this stage how would API knows that Authentication has been done?** **Does client send back the token to API?**
4. If Client does send the token. **How would API know it is the valid token?** and **When it will be expired?**
5. **Can someone please explain this kind of workflow between API and Client after Authentication?**

Comment: I have updated my answer. Let me know if you've got more questions.

Answer (score 3):

### Updated answer

Basically, what you are asking for is called the *Bearer Token Flow* which is described in detail [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750).

As seen from Figure 1 in [section 1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-1.3), once the client has authenticated successfully, an *Access Token* is granted from the *Authorization Server*. This token is then used for requesting resources by your *Resource Server* (your API). To do so, you need to include the token in recourse requests. The ways of doing so is described in [section two](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2).

Once you have received an access token, you will also optionally receive a [refresh token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.5). The refresh token should be used going forward to retrieve new access tokens once these expire or are invalidated. The refresh tokens are valid until access has been revoked or by [14 days as a default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564486/why-do-refresh-tokens-expire-after-14-days).
Although, as mentioned in my original answer, refresh tokens aren't yet supported in `Xamarin.Auth`, but a [well-defined blog post](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/11/13/mobile-authentication-with-xamarin-auth-and-refresh-tokens/) has defined how to support them.

Now, if any issues should occur once you try to request a resource, you'll get an `error_code` from the Resource Server depending on the issue at hand as seen in [section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-3.1).
As for instance, when the token is expired, the status code will be`invalid_token`. In this case, the user would need to re-authenticate if you are not using refresh tokens. If you are, and the refresh token is still valid, a new access token would be provided, and life would go on as normal.

As a last note, the [Access Token Reponse](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-22#section-4.2.2) includes an optional field called `expires_in`. You can use this field to know when an access token expires.

### Original answer

> 1. how would my Web API will know it has authenticated and now should
>    allow to access the endpoints?

As seen [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/authentication/oauth/#Authenticating_the_User), once `auth.Completed` is invoked and `AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs` is `IsAuthenticated`, you know that the user is authenticated using the given Identity Provider.

> 2. should i still need the Token Authentication mechanism in place for my app and API to communicated securely?

Yes. Once you get a token back from the Identity Provider, you should use that for going forward as it includes the privileges and identity of the user without exposing the username and password directly. You can read more about that [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/windows/desktop/aa374909(v=vs.85).aspx).

> 3. can i use the same token created by external authentication service
>    and store in database and use it to communicate between ? If so how
>    would i encounter situation where token is not valid?

Yes. In fact, as stated above, this is what you should do. You can use [JWT](https://jwt.io) to validate the token given from an Identity Provider to validate the token against your own API.

Although, going forward, you should use a [refresh token](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/refresh-token).
These may although not yet be supported by `Xamarin.Auth`. If you find they are not, [here](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/11/13/mobile-authentication-with-xamarin-auth-and-refresh-tokens/) is an excellent guide for how to handle the situation.

Good luck!