# When will a google oauth2 refresh token expired?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

When will a google oauth2 refresh token expired?

What I mean by expiration is  **expiration because of a certain time span had been passed**  (not because user has revoked access or because user has requested new refresh token)

I have done some research and none of them cited official google documentation (I can't find a valid google documentation too)

---

Some other questions said that it's never expired because of  **time** :

[Do Google refresh tokens expire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953983/do-google-refresh-tokens-expire)

https://community.fitbit.com/t5/Web-API-Development/Invalid-or-expired-refresh-tokens/td-p/1048159

While others said that it will expire (some say 14 days, others said 60 days)

this one said 14 days [Why do refresh tokens expire after 14 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564486/why-do-refresh-tokens-expire-after-14-days)

this one said 60 days https://blog.box.com/blog/oauth2-update-longer-lived-refresh-tokens/

this one said "very long time" (no exact time) https://medium.com/@bantic/more-oauth-2-0-surprises-the-refresh-token-1831d71f4af6

---

Because of a certain requirement, I need to have a refresh token that never expire because of  **passing of time** , so  *I require a refresh token that can still be used after like 20 years or so*

If refresh token expires before that time, then I will need to change my approach, so I need to know if they expires or not

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First let me start by saying there is now way to get a refresh token that will be guarantee to work after 20 years.  Technology will change in that time.  Also note i am answering from the stand point of Googles oauth servers each server is set up different different companies may have different rules as to when a refresh token will expire.   If you want some kind of industry standard you are best checking the [RFC for oauth](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)

A refresh token can expire.

1. If a user removes your access.
2. A user can have max 50 refresh tokens to your for your application.  That means if they authenticate your application 50 times you will have 50 outstanding and working refresh token when they authenticated it again the first one will expire and you will again will get a new one that will work.
3. If a refresh token hasn't been used in three - six months it will expire.
4. I have seen a few issues with google were huge batches of refresh tokens suddenly were expired this happens a few years ago in the fall.  I never got verification with google about what the problem was.  My guess is it was a time change issue as it happens the week everyone changed there time.

basically what all this means is no matter what your code should be able to request access of the user again if your refresh token has expired.

Comment: so that means as long as there's no major technology change (like deprecation or discontinuation of google oauth2 service), issue (like bugs, attacks, system fails, etc.), the user don't create new refresh token, the user don't revoke access, and I used the refresh token at least once every month to obtain new access token, then a refresh token will practically live forever, is that right?

Comment: Yup i have had them running for two years that has not expired.   Just remember that it can happen

Comment: if it's lifespan is at least 2 years then it might probably satisfy the requirement. thank you

Comment: Its at least that i just dont have any that have been hanging around that longer :)  In theory they should work indefinitely as long as you use them once a month.

Comment: Do you guys know if is there an endpoint to check if a refresh token has expired?

Comment: Best way to check if an access token or refresh token works.  Is to use it.    Try requesting an access token if it returns an error you have your answer.