# Refresh token google api php library

Tags: api, cookies, refresh, token

In my web application I am using google api php client for accessing the google tasks. I have followed some tutorials like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703700/google-api-authentication-for-server).

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$tasksService = new Google_TasksService($client);

$client->setAccessType('offline');

$cookie = $_COOKIE["token1"];

if(!empty($cookie)){
    $client->refreshToken($cookie);
}
else{
    $client->setAccessToken($client->authenticate($_GET['code']));
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $sessionToken = json_decode($_SESSION['access_token']);
    setcookie("token1", $sessionToken->refresh_token, time() + (20 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
}
```

When a user clicks the login URL he will be taken to a permission screen. If the user clicks ‘allow access’ he will be redirected to webpage as an authenticated user, thenI store the refresh_token in cookies. If refresh_token store in cookies, user will be redirected without again ‘allow access’. The problem in my code occurs when the user log off,  they can access the site as been logged out users. How to solve the problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Don't store the token in the user's cookie (it's a bad idea for all sorts of reasons, including your immediate problem).  You are already storing it in the session.  Just retrieve it from $_SESSION too.  Then make sure that the session expires when the user logs off.

Answer (score 0):

A more user friendly approach is to store the authorization code in the database associated with the user's id.  Then when he logs in it can be fetched without need for the user to authorize again (unless it has expired - if you get an error when trying to use it then just authorize again).  These are the functions that I use to store the authorization code along with the user id.  Variations of these _store and _get functions can be used to store any data associated with the user.

```
function _store_auth_code($auth_code) {
   $entry = array('auth_code'=> $auth_code,
                  'uid'      => $GLOBALS['user']->uid,
   );
   flashum_entry_delete('flashum_auth_code', $entry);
   flashum_entry_insert('flashum_auth_code', $entry);
}

function _get_auth_code() {
   $entry = array('uid' => $GLOBALS['user']->uid,
   );
   $return = flashum_entry_load('flashum_auth_code', $entry);
   if ($return) {
      return $return[0]->auth_code;
   } else
      return null;
}

function flashum_entry_load($db, $entry = array()) {
  // Read all fields from the flashum table.
  $select = db_select($db, 'flashum');
  $select->fields('flashum');

  // Add each field and value as a condition to this query.
  foreach ($entry as $field => $value) {
    $select->condition($field, $value);
  }
  // Return the result in object format.
  return $select->execute()->fetchAll();
}

function flashum_entry_delete($db, $entry) {
  db_delete($db)
    ->condition('uid', $entry['uid'])
    ->execute();
}

function flashum_entry_insert($db, $entry) {
  $return_value = NULL;
  try {
    $return_value = db_insert($db)
                    ->fields($entry)
                    ->execute();
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
    drupal_set_message(t('db_insert failed. Message = %message, query= %query',
      array('%message' => $e->getMessage(), '%query' => $e->query_string)), 'error');
  }
  return $return_value;
}
```