# Google Sign-In and logging in users

Tags: javascript, google-plus, google-authentication, google-signin

I have an app and I want to let people login using google sign-in. I need to check in the server what are the permissions of the current logged in user. (I have a table with email/role)

I read the documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in
from what I understand, when a user logs in using google, I get a callback and I can use the email and make calls to my server with it.

But what I don't understand is how can I make sure a malicious user won't see the javascript code and make a request to my server using any email he wants?

In other words, if the entire sign-in is in javascript, how can validate the identity in the server?

Comment: this might help you => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703700/google-api-authentication-for-server?rq=1

Comment: Read about oauth to understand how its not possible to fake the signin

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are doing the following:

- Signing in from the Web
- Using JavaScript for Sign-in and all data access

The following measures preventing malicious 3Ps from making API calls using your credentials / other user credentials:

- API calls are domain-restricted to the authorized origins you configured in the developer console
- API calls are restricted to the current credentials (e.g. only can get current user details / can only get credentials and tokens for the current user)

That said, let's move on to authN: making sure the user is who they claim to be. On the sign-in callback, you will receive a special token, the ID token, that has:

- The audience for the token (your client ID)
- The issuer of the token (user ID from profile)
- An issued timestamp
- An expiration timestamp
- etc..

These values are used to prevent forgery and avoid the [confused deputy problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confused_deputy_problem). For example, you use these values to check claims of who the user is, that the issuer of the token was you, and that the token has not expired. You also look at the ID token signature and validate it either using JWT functionality or by passing it to the Google verify token endpoint.

After verifying the user using the ID token, you can set a cookie for establishing a session and avoid having to verify the user on every API call.

Google provides token verification samples [here](https://github.com/googleplus/), for example, the [Google+ Token Verification sample in Ruby](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-verifytoken-ruby). Additionally, [the Google+ quickstart samples](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart) demonstrate establishing a client-server session in the "/connect" server endpoints on the server-side languages (Ruby, Python, .NET, etc).

Additional discussion on the topic is available in the [Identity Cookbook](https://developers.google.com/accounts/cookbook/functions/Authentication).